# Visual Studio Code Bracket Matching

Tags: match, visual-studio-code, element

I'm using Visual Studio Code for web development. It's very useful tool but when i select a tag, element etc. Visual Studio Code show all the same tag, element or etc. I only know where tag is closed. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not supported yet, as you can see in [this open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2915).

Go there and add a :thumbs_up:, so they could priorize in the next releases, or someone else would create an extension for that.